# Zoom in on webview on appearing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, zooming

I have a UIWebView that loads a PDF that is setup in landscape format and is very hard to read on the iPhone screen.  My code is like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_entry.articleUrl];   
NSLog(@"%@",url);
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
self.title = _entry.articleTitle;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

What are some ways I could set it to be zoomed in more and possibly moved over to the right hand side of the top pdf page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make sure your UIWebView has scalesPageToFit property enabled

```
self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

And then in your HTML add this tag inside the 'head' tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

you can make **maximum-scale=1.5** if that will make it appears better.

I am not sure about if it is a PDF file how to add these tags to it. Maybe you can add the tags and implement the PDF inside the html file.

Here is how to embeded a PDF file inside HTML

```
<embed src="filename.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

Good luck!

Comment: It is a PDF on a website, so I have no option to edit the HTML

Comment: @user717452 I know, that's why I said try to implement the PDF inside your an html file. I will edit my answer and demonstrate for you a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS  version less than 5:

```
 UIScrollView *sv = [[_webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
 [sv setZoomScale:2.0 animated:NO];// increase scale factor to zoom more
```

In IOS 5:

```
  [_webView.scrollView setZoomScale:2.0 animated:NO];// increase scale factor to zoom more
```

You can use **content offset** to move to top right hand side

Comment: Am developing for iOS 5 and higher, and that made no difference